Is the "new" method name reserved?
Coming from this helpful question/answer: Constructor chaining in PowerShell - call other constructors in the same class.
To be consistent with the way you call a constructor (e.g. [car]::new()) and because "the hidden keyword" doesn't completely hide the method anyways, I am considering to use the method name new() (rather than init() for this constructor "helper" method in my classes. e.g.:
hidden new([string]$make) { $this.new($make, $null) }

It appears to work fine but somehow I fear that there might be a catch by doing so.
Is there any reason I should avoid the name "new" for a PowerShell class method?

there would be a conflict if you tried to use hidden static new([string]$make) otherwise should be fine

@SantiagoSquarzon, thanks for the comment. Meaning if I try to address the method, I will just get the constructor (defined by the system) instead, which is exactly how I want it to react.

Right, you'd need to use unnecessary reflection to make it work [MyClass].GetMethod('new').Invoke($null, $this) and the overload definitions would show the actual method instead of the ctor definitions. so yeah, just avoid using static new and you should be good

"To be consistent with the way you call a constructor" - why are you trying to impose "consistency" across two different member types? Your initializer method is not a constructor, don't try to disguise it as such :)

i also agree with Mathias, wouldn't use or recommend new as a method name. my intent was just to answer with the possible limitations of using it

FWIW I tend in the opposite direction and would prefer hidden Initialize(...){} - tells you exactly what it does, little room for ambiguity :)

@MathiasR.Jessen, SantiagoSquarzon,  thanks, I appreciate your valuable comments!



Is there any reason I should avoid the name new for a PowerShell Class method?

From a strictly technical consideration and leaving aside personal preference / opinion, as long as the method is an instance method, then using new as its name shouldn't be a problem.
As noted in comments, there would be a problem if the method was a static one as you would be conflicting with the new intrinsic member.
The first problem would be the need to use reflection to invoke your method in the .ctor:
class Test {
    [string] $MyParam

    Test() {
        [Test].GetMethod('new').Invoke($null, $this)
    }

    Test([string] $myParam) {
        $this.MyParam = $myParam
    }

    hidden static new([Test] $instance) {
        $instance.MyParam = 'default value'
    }
}

[Test]::new()

# MyParam
# -------
# default value

[Test]::new('other value')

# MyParam
# -------
# other value

The second problem would be that the overload definitions would be all messed up as they would be showing your method overloads instead of the actual constructor overloads:
[Test]::new

# OverloadDefinitions
# -------------------
# public static void new(Test instance);

The expected here would be (same definitions as if you were doing [Test].GetConstructors()):
[Test]::new

# OverloadDefinitions
# -------------------
# public Test();
# public Test(string myParam);

